# Upload document to Server using HttpPost

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, http-post

The application "A" requires to upload a word-file [as a byte array] to a external application using POST.

The filecontent should be added as named parameter in the request body and have to make a POST request to upload the file.

I have a sample code, but in java. I would like to write an equivalent C# code. But In C#, could not find a similar object like MultiPartEntity.

java code snippet:

```
String restURL = HOSTURL + "/rest/upload/0b002f4780293c18";        
String fileName = "testRestUploadByFolderID" + Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() + ".txt";        
File testFile = createNewFile("C:/Temp/rest/" + fileName);        
FileBody content = new FileBody(testFile, "application/octet-stream");        
System.out.println(" File Name : " + content.getFilename() + " ... "                +     content.getTransferEncoding());        
MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);        
reqEntity.addPart("filename", new StringBody(fileName));        
reqEntity.addPart("uploadfile", content);        
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(restURL);        
httpPost.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");        
httpPost.setEntity(reqEntity);                 

// Post the request        
String response = httpclient.execute(httpPost, new DefaultResponseHandler());
```

Could you please post some links which explains how to make named parameter in  C# to upload a fileContent

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a multipart content post, maybe this can help:

**Note:**

This is the *.net 4.5 async way* of doing it, but you can use this solution in .net 4 too installing some Nuget packages:

- https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Build
- http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http

Code:

```
using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
using (var multiPartContent = new MultipartFormDataContent())
{

     httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(BaseAddress);

     var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(*filebytes*);

     //Create content header
     fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ontentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
                {
                    FileName = *fileName*
                };

       //Add file to the multipart request
       multiPartContent.Add(fileContent);

       //Add any other file?
       ...


      //Post it
      HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync("hostURL", multiPartContent);

 }
```

IMO this is the cleanest way of doing it on .net, forget about dirty [HttpRequests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.aspx)